# iOS App Versioning: can AppStore Hotfix Version be lower than Beta Version?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

We continuously have builds of our iOS app in Testflight for testing. Latest version in TestFlight is 1.1.0.
Now we encountered a huge bug in our current AppStore version (1.0.3). Now we want to push a hot fix with version 1.0.4.

Is this possible, or may we get trouble, because we already submitted 1.1.0 for testing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK only version numbers for releases must be in increasing order, so you should be fine. Even if not, users don't really care about version numbers, so you might as well upload your hotfix as 1.1.0 and bump your test version to 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Testfilght build are used for two purposes -

```
1: Internal/External Testing 
2: Apple Store Build.
```

Once you have released the Test Flight build with version 1.0.2 or 1.0.3 to Apple Store then you are not allowed to upload the next build in same series into TestFlight. Which means your next TestFlight release will be in series of 2 (2.0.0 or 2.0.1).

In your case you can create a Test Flight version 2.0.1 and then create Apple Store version 1.0.4. After this Connect the Apple Store version(1.0.4) with the Hotfix Testflight version(2.0.1) and review/release the App.

So in App Store the build version will always show 1.0.4 but internally it will be 2.0.1 (which can be used for other coding purposes like for Firebase Remoteconfig etc)